# Is a colon necessary after the phrase "some of these include"?

Tags: grammar

For example,

1) "Some of these included art design class and working with animals without a home"

2) "Some of these included: art design class and working with animals without a home"

Comment: It's certainly not *necessary*, and if a colon is used, common style would say it should be something like *some of these were included:* or *some of these included the following:*. (It's also difficult to say, since the single sentence, outside of any context, is actually just a sentence fragment. You should really provide at least the sentence that comes before.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct punctuation after "as follows"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/394859/what-is-the-correct-punctuation-after-as-follows) (closed as POB).

Comment: By the way, how many of the activities included both art design class and working with animals?

Comment: @Anton what if the activities were part of a group of related courses offered, i.e. to help those recovering from post traumatic stress (re Merriam-Webster definition of 'include' below)

Comment: @Anton Sherwood "Do not use a colon before a list unless the items are in apposition to an introductory word" (Words into Type, 3rd Edition, Prentice-Hall, p181)... What the hell does that mean??

Comment: @user365664 Are you saying the construction is analogous to “Some of the recipes include garlic and ginger”?

Comment: I see this question has been bumped, but there is no single right answer; such matters are a question of style. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, adopt a [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) appropriate to your audience and tastes and be consistent in its application.

Answer (score 3):

“When the introduction is not a complete sentence and one or more of the items of the list are needed to complete it, no colon or dash should be used” (Words into Type, 3rd Edition, Prentice-Hall, Englewood Cliffs, NJ, 1974, p. 181). “Some of these included” is not a sentence, and the items *art* and *class* are needed to complete it (that is, make it into a sentence), so there should not be a colon after *included*. Also, *include* indicates that what follows is “part of a whole or group” (Merriam-Webster online, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/include), so “some of these included” is redundant. “Some of these were” would be better.

Comment: Or “These included”.

Comment: Some more examples... "Wrong: ...produced in large quantities, such as: cacao beans, coffee, fruits,
and Panama hats. [The colon should be omitted.]" according to (Words into Type, 3rd Edition, Prentice-Hall, p181).

Comment: Some further examples..."Wrong: The principal criteria determining the selection of the site were: location,
initial cost, suitability, and convenience to transportation. [The colon
should be omitted.]" according to (Words into Type, 3rd Edition, Prentice-Hall, p181).

Comment: But then we have this rule which contradicts your answer: "Rule 1: Use the colon after a **complete sentence** to introduce a list of items when introductory words such as namely, for example, or that is do not apply or are not appropriate." link: https://data.grammarbook.com/blog/colons/colons/