# What does it mean for someone to say "I've read something with interest"

Tags: meaning, writing, email, letter-writing

Is there any positive or negative connotation attached to this phrase?

Suppose I sent someone something by email, and the reply begins:

> "I've read your email with interest."

Is that good or bad?

Comment: That depends. Connotation depends on context, text, and subtext. Is this a statement from a Labour MP talking about recent news articles in the Guardian e.g.  the latest drinking party at 10 Downing? Or is it two intellectuals discussing a new publication? Whatever...for me, it sounds a little pompous...

Comment: Suppose I sent someone something, and the reply begins "I've read your email with interest."

Comment: That example helps a little... *you should edit to provide that as well as any other info applicable to help clarify the question.*  ex. What is your relationship with that person? Right now, it sounds like a standard greeting with "low calories." In a case like this, context really helps

Comment: Hello Fraïssé...your question will be placed automatically on the re-open queue once you make a few necessary edits.

Comment: I have voted to re-open your post https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/394859/what-is-the-correct-punctuation-after-as-follows...   Consider editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The sentence means exactly what it says:** I read this thing and I found it interesting.

That in itself is generally a positive connotation - things that are interesting are generally better than things that are not interesting.

However the reason for the interest may not be positive. If your boss reads something from you that he expected to agree with his views (which would not have been interesting to him) but in fact it disagrees, that might make it more interesting to him but not necessarily good for you.

However that is entirely from context and can't be deduced from the language.

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not think we should be answering this LQ question until it is clarified and researched. I have been prompting the OP to clarify...it is already 2 VTC

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ That's ok. Feel free to close. I have closed questions with 72000 views https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/394859/what-is-the-correct-punctuation-after-as-follows I'm sure it will be helpful to someone

Comment: @Fraïssé Your question is closed because it does not follow basic site guidelines. I suggest that you review the [Help Page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help)